# Some questions related to tornado httpserver and httpclient

Tags: tornado

Question 1:

tornado.httpserver is a non-blocking http server. Is there any blocking http server?

Question 2:

Does asynchronous always mean non-blocking? Does synchronous always mean blocking?

Question 3:

Are tornado.curl_httpclient and tornado.simple_httpclient both non-blocking, aka, asynchronous?

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: yes, Flask and Django and SimpleHTTPServer other multithreaded HTTP servers written in Python are "blocking". If you write code that uses one of those servers to implement an HTTP server application, your code will not use "yield" or "await" or callbacks to implement its logic.

Question 2: Pedants will say that "synchronous" and "blocking" are distinct and that "asynchronous" and "non-blocking" are distinct. I expect several of them to say so in answer to this question. However, they are effectively interchangeable ideas for your purposes: synchronous and blocking are synonyms, and asynchronous and non-blocking are synonyms.

Question 3: As the docs say, [`tornado.simple_httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient` is non-blocking](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/latest/httpclient.html#module-tornado.simple_httpclient), as is CurlHTTPClient. I suggest [you read Tornado's docs about async](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/latest/guide/async.html), it includes definitions of sync and async, and code examples for both sync and async HTTP clients.